# D: How to create a required method with arbitrary parameters in \abstract class?

Tags: d

Say I have an abstract class for a dog, defined as below:

```
abstract class Dog {
    public:
        uint age;
        abstract void moveDog();
        abstract void feedDog();
        abstract void playFetch();
}
```

Now I want to create two different classes that extend Dog, but the moveDog, feedDog, and playFetch methods each have different implementations AND different arguments, such as these two:

```
class BigDog: Dog {
    public:
        override void moveDog(uint steps) {...}
        override void feedDog(uint numFoodBowls) {...}
        override void playFetch(uint timeToPlay, float throwDistance) {...}
}

class SmallDog: Dog {
    public:
        override void moveDog(uint steps, float direction) {...}
        override void feedDog(float foodWeight) {...}
        override void playFetch(float throwStrength, uint timeToPlay, float throwDistance) {...}
}
```

Is this possible in D? I simply want to force all subclasses of Dog to implement three methods with the same name, but I do not want to specify the arguments and implementations of said methods.

Comment: What would be the point of an interface with incompatible arguments? I mean like what are you trying to achieve and why does it need to be forced? I have a few ideas but need to know why to pick what is best lol

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe because I want to ensure that all sublasses of Dog have a feedDog() method implementation, but each subclass's implementation of said method may have different arguments. Maybe it doesn't make sense to do it this way. And of course, the Dog example is just an example.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't really make any sense from an OOP perspective, since the interface wouldn't be compatible between them. But you could force it kinda by doing a `static assert(__traits(hasMember, SmallDog, "feedDog"));`. sort of...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you can achieve what you want, and still make some sense, is if you can come up with all possible (common) parameters, and use the defaults.

What I have in mind is something like:

```
import std.stdio;


abstract class Dog {
  public:
  uint age;
  abstract void moveDog(uint steps, float direction=float.nan);
  abstract void feedDog(uint numFoodBowls=-1, float foodWeight=float.nan);
  abstract void playFetch(uint timeToPlay, float throwDistance, float throwStrength=float.nan);
}

class BigDog: Dog {
  public:
  override void moveDog(uint steps, float direction) { 
    writeln(direction);
  }
  override void feedDog(uint numFoodBowls=-1, float foodWeight=float.nan) {}
  override void playFetch(uint timeToPlay, float throwDistance, float throwStrength=float.nan) {}
}

class SmallDog: Dog {
  public:
  override void moveDog(uint steps, float direction) { 
    writeln(direction);
  }
  override void feedDog(uint numFoodBowls=-1, float foodWeight=float.nan) {}
  override void playFetch(uint timeToPlay, float throwDistance, float throwStrength) {}
}

void main() { 
  auto obj = new BigDog();
  obj.moveDog(5, -0.1f); // -0.1
}
```

Finally, as others pointed out, if your "behaviour" (methods define behaviour) is different for every "kind" (subclass) of Dog, then it should not be in the interface (abstract class)...